# WinForm progressbar not working when I open that form in Wpf application?

Tags: wpf, winforms, progress-bar

I created a Windows form project in Visual studio and used a progress bar with style as marquee and I created another wpf project and added windows project reference to the newly created wpf project and call the form in a button click event as

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Form1 form = new Form1();
   form.Show();
}
```

But the progress bar inside the form is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the above issue by adding the following lines

```
 System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
 System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```